# It is possible to forward all audio to the Android smartphone via wi-fi?

Tags: wi-fi, audio, streaming

Are there apps/methods that allow for the sound to be forwarded to the smartphone?

So if I would watch a YouTube video on the PC, I could also hear the sound via the smartphone.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use [Airfoil Speakers for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rogueamoeba.AirfoilSpeakers), which is free, but requires a [server](http://rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/) component (Airfoil) to be installed on your PC. The free version plays audio fine for 10 minutes and then overlays noise. The license key is $25.

Answer (score 0):

A cheaper option is  [SoundWire "Free version - Market Link"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.georgie.SoundWireFree&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwiY29tLmdlb3JnaWUuU291bmRXaXJlRnJlZSJd) the free version will speak every 45 mins (just a nag) the paid version is under USD 4, link to it inside the same market link. Logically try the free version first. Sadly its PC only, not sure why as as far as i can see its a lite VNC app, sending only the audio and not keystrokes or anything else.

Honestly i find it extremely surprising that no one has made a Bluetooth headset, or similar profile for a phone. It would be very useful also for HTPCs as a kind of cheap (but very good quality) wireless headphones.