# Is it possible to use one android as a remote speaker for all audio on another android, using no more hardware than an unmodified wifi access point?

Tags: audio, streaming

I have an android phone (Sony Xperia Compact Z1 / Stock) with an "eh" speaker, and a tablet (Kindle Fire 7" HD / Cyanogen) with amazing speakers. I use the phone a lot to listen to audiobooks, but at home i'd like to be able to use the tablet so i can hear the audiobooks over other noises.

I currently use Smart Audiobook Player since it seems to be the best audiobook software on the market, but it cannot synch progress between different devices, or stream audio between them on its own.

So i would like to stream *all audio* that is currently playing on my phone, over to my tablet and have it play via the tablet's speakers.

I suppose this should be feasible via Bluetooth or Wifi, but:

- No Bluetooth solutions seemed to work, none of them even indicated being able to connect between the two devices.
- No Wifi solutions seem to exist that can work with only the two android devices and the unmodified Wifi AP.

Did i overlook some piece of software that can do this?

Comment: Progress neither syncs in any of the apps available.

Comment: @SantoshKumar I have no idea why you tell me this. If i can stream the audio directly to another device from the one device that tracks progress, then there is no need for synching.

Comment: Here are three similar questions. They all deal with Android-PC streaming, but maybe something suggested there will work for you:
http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/95845/realtime-transfer-stream-the-audio-to-another-mobile-device-directly-witho?rq=1
http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29566/how-can-i-stream-audio-from-my-phone-over-wifi-to-a-speaker-or-receiver
http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/44264/it-is-possible-to-forward-all-audio-to-the-android-smartphone-via-wi-fi?rq=1

Comment: @MichelfrancisBustillos The answers in the linked questions either try to do something wildly different from what i described, or flat out did not work on my devices.

Answer (score 1):

[THIS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ilumnis.btplayerfree) app does the trick...

You need to install it on both Android devices and pair them. Then put the tablet in ListenMUSIC over Blueetooth mode and the the phone in shareMUSIC over Bluetooth mode.

HOPE IT HELPS...

Answer (score 0):

Your question led me to this app call AmpMe (both [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amp.android) an iOS) which promises to do exactly or probably, something similar to your heart desire.

[AmpMe](http://www.ampme.com/):

> Sync your phone with friends to create the world's most portable sound system

With the app above, you can play sound to even multiple tablets.

Comment: Tried it and it was only able to act as an audio file/stream player which directed remote clients. It was not able to stream all audio as mentioned in my question, nor even specific programs' audio (which could be a suitable substitute.)

Comment: Okay. Maybe the exact solution to your problem isn't yet created, perhaps an opportunity to solve a problem?

Comment: There is an opportunity to solve a problem here. I'm just baffled it hasn't been done yet, since there are already hundreds of bluetooth speakers available for purchase, and all that would be needed for this is to have an android device act as a bluetooth speaker.